# Finding d of RSA given e and phi using SageMath

Tags: rsa

I am trying to find $d$ given $e$ and $\varphi(n)$. I found a solution online but I don't really understand why it works.

```
sage: bezout = xgcd(e, phi); bezout 
(1, 4460824882019967172592779313, -1667095708515377925087033035)

sage: d = Integer(mod(bezout[1], phi)) ; d
4460824882019967172592779313

sage: mod(d * e, phi)
1
```

Found an explanation of this online

```
ex + φ(n)y = gcd(e,φ(n))
           = 1
Re-arrange:
ex = -φ(n)y + 1

ex mod φ(n) = 1, so x = d
```

but I get why the second line of code is needed if $x=d$ then
`d = bezout[1]`.Why is there a mod by $\varphi(n)$ again to obtain $d$?

Answer (score 1):

This is about the XGCD [implementation of Sagemath.](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_standard/sage/arith/misc.html)

> XGCD(a, b)
> Return a triple (g,s,t) such that g=s⋅a+t⋅b=gcd(a,b). 
> g, s, t - such that g=s⋅a+t⋅b 
> **Note There is no guarantee that the returned cofactors (s and t) are minimal.**

Since the returned cofactors are not guaranteed to be minimal, it is the user's responsibility to reduce the value to be less than $\varphi(n)$